# PageCurl animations on ViewPager transitions?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

Here's a demo of what a page curl animation looks like:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVZHN_o45sg

There are a couple of page curl animation libraries:

- https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl
- https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl

They are meant to work with Bitmap Drawables and not necessarily ViewGroups. If was wondering if anyone has come up with a similar page curl transition for ViewPagers.

Comment: have you seen this http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/10/simple-viewpager-for-android.html

Comment: @RachelGallen That blog has nothing about using page curl animations in ViewPager. It just describes how to set up a simple view pager.

Comment: try this http://www.apkzoom.com/Tools/Android-UI-Patterns-184812.html#.UV6WkJPcmlU

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks. But they are simply demos of the libraries I already mentioned above.

Comment: @AnupCowkur http://techie-manoj.com/?p=146 try with this link.

Comment: Morphing View Groups is actually pretty hard (unless you do it the Bitmap way). I'd suggest dropping down to `BitmapDrawable`s by drawing the ViewGroup to a Canvas and replacing it in the layout for the purposes of animating. It's hacky but you'd be able to use the existing libraries relatively easily.

Comment: Hi, I am searching same. Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Not a straight way..but, How about creating the bitmap of view group by getDrawingCache() method and pass the bitmap to library.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/wajahatkarim3/EasyFlipViewPager/) is a library that I just come across; it has a nice page curl transformation. It is not the exact same page curl that you want; but maybe some remedy to anyone

**How it looks**

[image]

**Dependency**

```
implementation 'com.wajahatkarim3.easyflipviewpager:easyflipviewpager:1.0.0'
```

**Usage**

```
// Get ViewPager and Set Adapter        
myViewPager = findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this);
myViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

// Create an object of page transformer
BookFlipPageTransformer bookFlipPageTransformer = new BookFlipPageTransformer();

// Enable / Disable scaling while flipping. If true, then next page will scale in (zoom in). By default, its true.
bookFlipPageTransformer.setEnableScale(true);

// The amount of scale the page will zoom. By default, its 5 percent.
bookFlipPageTransformer.setScaleAmountPercent(10f);

// Assign the page transformer to the ViewPager.
myViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, bookFlipPageTransformer);
```