# How to add page curl effect for viewpager

Tags: android, user-interface, android-viewpager

I want to add page curl effect when user swipe from one view to another view in the ViewPager. I have study the [ViewPager.PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html)

But not able get idea how to implement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android activity page curl animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727907/android-activity-page-curl-animation)

Comment: You may check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829408/pagecurl-animations-on-viewpager-transitions/58212631#58212631#answer-58212631

Answer (score 0):

You can use below link for better curl effects, [Curl Effects Lib](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)
[image]